# MySQL sumar todas las columnas(excepto la primera) de una tabla que va aumentando de columnas cada semana, ignorar NULL

Tags: mysql, sum, tabla-dinámica

Tengo una tabla que incrementa una columna cada semana, necesito **mostrar la suma de todas las columnas excepto de la primera, algunos campos pueden ser Null**, necesito que se los considere como cero 0:
[image: Tabla ejemplo]

Actualmente tengo hasta pts_fecha_9 pero la siguiente semana se creara la columna pts_fecha_10 y asi sucesivamente. Estoy atento a respuestas

Comment: Ese diseño es *un disparo en el pie*; la presentación no debe resolverse en la persistencia.

Answer (score 1):

¿por que agregas una columna cada semana?
seria mas fácil si modificas la tabla para que solo sean 3 campos

```
Login_Id, pts, fecha
```

de esta manera podrías hacer consultas como por ejemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(pts) FROM TABLA WHERE Login_Id = 1 AND fecha between '2021-04-12' and '2022-04-12'
```

con esta sentencia obtendrías la suma de la columna pts de un rango de fechas
o en su defecto si necesitas usar el numero de la semana tambien lo puedes hacer.

Comment: En realidad la tabla pertenece a un juego de futbol, donde login_id representa al usuario y pts_fecha_# representa los puntos que el usuario hizo en la fecha_# del torneo.
Durante todo el torneo tengo q poder consultar los puntos que hizo cada usuario en cada fecha  y tambien los puntos totales hasta el momento que para eso es la suma que pido.

Comment: con la modificación que sugiero, este problema que mencionas se puede solucionar. Login_id seguiria siendo el usuario, pts los puntos de ganados en la fecha, y el campo fecha pues logicamente para la fecha, lo unico diferente es que tendrás varios filas por cada usuario, en vez de una fila por cada usuario
al final para obtener la suma puedes hacer la consulta que escribí en la respuesta.

Comment: de igual manera si insistes en resolverlo como lo tienes de la forma original, existe una forma para obtener los nombres de los campos de una tabla, para tu caso seria algo similar a esto `SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TU_BASE_DE_DATOS' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TU_TABLA' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'pts_fecha_%'; `

sin embargo estuve investigando y no he encontrado forma de meter esto dentro de la función SUM

Comment: Fernando, muchas gracias por la ayuda ya va tomando forma con el ultimo script que me pasaste, estare haciendo pruebas.
Respecto al otro método que sugieres me obligaria a cambiar muchas lineas en el codigo python que genera esta tabla entonces lo tomaria como una última opción.

Comment: es un placer poder ayudar aunque sea un poco, en caso se que logres solucionarlo, compártenos la forma en la que lo solucionaste respondiendo a tu pregunta.